# Complex analysis question, maximum principle application

Tags: complex-analysis, transformation, analyticity, maximum-principle

Let $\Omega=\{z, \text{Re}z>0\}$ Suppose that $f$ is continuous in the closure of $\Omega$ and $f$ is holomoprhic on $\Omega$ and there are constants $A<\infty $ and $\alpha<1$ such that $$|f(z)|<Ae^{|z|^\alpha}$$
for all $z\in\Omega$ futhermore, $|f(iy)|\leq1 $ for all real $y$. Prove that $|f(z)|\leq 1$ in $\Omega$.

How would approach this problem? Is the 3 lines theorem helpful?, then we need find a bounded function involving $f$ then apply the 3-line theorem. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you allowed to use the Phragmen-Lindelof principle? If you are then this is a direct consequence.

Comment: Have not gone over that in class so I m hoping they are other ways to prove it

Comment: So how would you prove this using phragmen lindeloff? Mapping the strip to the half plane? By the exponential map? I did not get the desired result by doing so

Comment: There are two versions of Phragmen-Lindelof, one for strips and one for sectors.

Comment: I just proved this actually, but thanks for your answer